# How to make filter Using multiple data value using Django Rest Framework and Angular 11

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I am facing problem with searching and filtering in my project. I am using Django rest framework and PostgreSQL for backend and Angular 11 for frontend.
my model class is

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    domain = models.ManyToManyField(Domain)
    environment = models.ManyToManyField(Environment)
    tools_and_technology = models.ManyToManyField(ToolsAndTechnology)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True,upload_to=uploadPath)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

if a user select tools and technology for a project like C# or Java the result should be filtured and display. A user can filter by tools and technology, domain, environment. Each field can be multiple value. How can I solve this??
TIA

Answer (score 0):

this can be done like below.
considering you will be passing which filter to apply through the GET api params,
inside views.py for this function,
you get data this way

```
data = request.data.copy()
```

then

maintain a filter variable,
`kwargs = {}`

save the possible filter values,

```
tools_and_technology = data.get('tools_and_technology',None)
domain = data.get('domain',None)
environment = data.get('environment',None)
```

now, for each,

```
if tools_and_technology:
    kwargs['tools_and_technology'] = tools_and_technology
if domain:
    kwargs['domain'] = domain
if environment:
    kwargs['environment'] = environment
```

if you support a list of values for each filter, then you can add `__in` in the query set and make sure, that the values are in a list

```
if tools_and_technology:
    kwargs['tools_and_technology__in'] = tools_and_technology
if domain:
    kwargs['domain__in'] = domain
if environment:
    kwargs['environment__in'] = environment
```

later, use this kwargs in the queryset

`queryset = Project.objects.filter(**kwargs)`

you can return this queryset through a serializer.